# Sort bibliography by eprint

Tags: biblatex, biber, sorting

I would like to sort the bibliography by eprint but it does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{eprint}{
    \sort[direction=descending]{\field{eprint}}
}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{year}{
    \sort[direction=descending]{\field{year}}
}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{A01,
    author = {Author, A.},
    year = {2014},
    title = {Alpha},
    eprint = {1402.1354},
}
@article{B02,
    author = {Buthor, B.},
    year = {2016},
    title = {Bravo},
    eprint = {1602.1354},
}
@article{C03,
    author = {Cuthor, C.},
    year = {2015},
    title = {Charlie},
    eprint = {1504.1354},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}
\newrefcontext[sorting=eprint]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\newrefcontext[sorting=year]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Is this due to the verbatim type of the eprint field? Is there an easy way to fix that?

Comment: The log generated by `biber --trace` suggests `\field{eprint}` is not recognised properly as a field by the sorting subroutines. Please report this as a bug at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues. If I understand correctly this is indeed specific to *verbatim* (and also *uri*) fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @moewe, I filed a bug report (https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/263). For me, mapping the eprint field for sorting to another field worked:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{eprint}{
    \sort[direction=descending]{\field{sortkey}}
}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@article{A01,
    author = {Author, A.},
    year = {2014},
    title = {Alpha},
    eprint = {1402.1354},
}
@article{B02,
    author = {Buthor, B.},
    year = {2016},
    title = {Bravo},
    eprint = {1602.1354},
}
@article{C03,
    author = {Cuthor, C.},
    year = {2015},
    title = {Charlie},
    eprint = {1504.1354},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
            \step[fieldsource=eprint]
            \step[fieldset=sortkey,origfieldval]
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\newrefcontext[sorting=eprint]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for reporting the issue. The workaround is pretty much what I would have suggested as well.